# How to do specific HTTP POST in objective c (working curl line included)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, curl, http-post

My API needs to receive some parameters and image via HTTP POST. In curl it is done with:

```
curl http://someurl -F 'service[lat]=12.22' -F 'sevice[lng]=12.33' -F 'service[user_id]=4' -F 'service[location]=Vienna' -F 'service[image]=@tour.jpg'
```

How can it be done in objective C (iphone)?
I guess it be done with content type set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"random string of your choosing";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// file
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// length
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"size\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",imageData.length] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// lat
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"lat\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lat] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    

// lon
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"lon\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lon] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// location
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"location\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:location] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// user_id
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:user_id] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// set request body
[request setHTTPBody:body];

//bon voyage
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/) framework if you want to avoid the hassle of building the post data yourself.

Example from documentation :

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"names"];
[request addPostValue:@"George" forKey:@"names"];
[request addFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photos"];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"george.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photos"];
```

I use it in all my projects, it's very robust and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Please do NOT use ASIHTTPRequest. From the developer's homepage:

> Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)

I've heard good things about [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/)

But implementing POST Requests via `NSURLRequest` is not that hard and you do not depend on another library.

Comment: just because the main developer stopped working on the project doesn't mean people should stop using it. It's very robust bullet proofed with tons of unit tests and if you need updates there are many active forks on github...

Comment: Yes i am trying with nsurlrequest, but i have trouble adding all parameters.